# Referencing external view with durandal compose binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, view, durandal, composition

I have my project structure:

```
App
        - Admin
            - views
            - viewmodels
            - main.js  
        - User
        - SuperUser
        - Common
            - views
            - viewmodels
```

Each role in my WebSite has it's own durandal SPA with `main.js` and other blackjack.

Now the question,

in my `shell.html` in `Admin` SPA I want to use `view` from `Common` folder.

In case of `view` in `Admin` I simply do `compose binding`:

```
<div>
    <header data-bind="compose: { view: 'nav' }"></header>
        <section id="content" class="main container-fluid shell"
                 data-bind="router: { transition: 'entrance'}"></section>
        <footer data-bind="compose: { view: 'footer' }"></footer>
</div>
```

And `views` from App/Admin/views are available. 
How can I reference views from App/Coomon/views/*?

It's simple with js component, I just declare as a module and then pass it to the define. And I just stuck with views.

I tried smth like:

```
    <div>
            <header data-bind="compose: { view: '../Common/views/nav' }"></header>
            <header data-bind="compose: { view: '../../Common/views/nav' }"></header>
        </div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right way with relative paths. Only add `.html` to the view and it will work.

For example in your folder structure:

In the admin views, for example `adminShell.html` you can compose the `nav.html` in `Common/Views` by using:

```
compose: { view: '../../Common/views/nav.html }
```

By looking in the source code I found a better way. There is a undocumented (I haven't found the documentation yet) feature for the compose binding. You can specify an area where the view is located. So for the given example you should come with:

```
compose: { view: 'views/nav', area: 'Common' }
```

Comment: thanks) adding `*.html` works just fine for me)
unfortunately `area` does not, it would be much more elegant solution

Comment: @makambi I wonder if that's true, that it really would be more elegant to use `areas`. You have multiple SPAs.  Areas are best leveraged within a _single_ SPA.  But do you really feel that you need separate SPAs for this scenario?  Just curious.

Comment: I didn't catch that part. Areas won't work when for example the main is in Admin.

Comment: @EricTaylor, maybe you are right and `areas` within single SPA would be more clear. Such structure was chosen to separate logic and provide security for each `SPA entry point`. Where server side controller and view decides render page or not.

I have lack of knowledge in SPA, and at that moment it sound like a good way.

Comment: @makambi Yes, we went down that path as well in the beginning.  Finally, we elected to go with 1 SPA and no areas. But, then, we're using Web API 2.1 on the backend with an entirely client-side experience.  Had we gone with MVC, we would have chosen 1 SPA with areas.

Comment: @EricTaylor, thanks for comments. I will reconsider my solution since I am using Web API on the backend either.